# EXPO : Share Audio File

Tags: react-native, expo

Good morning,
i'm trying to share an audio file with whatsapp.
But when i create the Album , i don't know how to get the proper Uri , and when i try to use original asset , response this error.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failed to share the file: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/recording-027dc98c-b62b-4699-9dbd-fd075cecd87d.3gp]
```

Thank you for your time

Full example on : https://snack.expo.io/@tilenozz/recorder
(Wait a bit after allow on first permission , take a bit )

```
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(this.recording.getURI());
        MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Sveglia_Social_App', asset)
            .then(() => {
                console.log(asset)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('err', error);
            });
Sharing.shareAsync(asset.uri)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
await Sharing.shareAsync(this.recording.getURI());
```

I am not sure if  3gp format supported for share in Whatsapp.

Comment: It Worked ! actually 3gp is not supperted , enough change file extension !
Thank you for help !

Comment: nop." Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."